# Hilt repository injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I've been trying to resolve my issue but I can't find anything...

MyAppApplication.kt :

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyAppApplication  : Application()
```

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity()
```

MyViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val myRepository: MyRepository,
 private val appPreference: AppPreference) : ViewModel(){}
```

MyRepository.kt

```
interface MyRepository { 
    fun test()
}

class MyRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val service:Service): MyRepository { 
    override fun test() { print("") }
}
```

HiltModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {
    private const val BASE_URL = "..."

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getGsonConverterFactory(): GsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(
        GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
    )

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getRetrofit(gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .build()


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideService(retrofitClient: Retrofit) = retrofitClient.create(Service::class.java)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getAppPreference(application: Application) :AppPreference = AppPreferenceImpl(application)

}


@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @ViewModelScoped
    @Provides
    fun getMyRepository(myRepository: MyRepositoryImpl): MyRepository = myRepository
}
```

failed with 2 errors

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.app.repository.MyRepositoryImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
> com.example.myapp.repository.MyRepositoryImmpl is injected at....

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Do you have any idea of what I am missing?

Thanks you!

Complementary informations:

- I have tried switching ViewModelScope to Singleton.
- I have tried switching Object RepositoryModule to

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    @ViewModelScoped
    abstract fun bindMyRepository(myRepository: MyRepositoryImpl): MyRepository
  }
```

- I have tried having them all inside One HiltModule Object
- I have tried

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    fun getMyRepository(service: Service): MyRepository = MyRepositoryImpl(service)
}
```

But same issue mentioned.

Comment: You should try provide repository with `SingletonComponent`.

Comment: @DươngMinh Hey, I tried with that too, not working.

Comment: Try Marking Repository class with @Singleton annotation

Comment: How do you provide `service` to your `getMyRepository(service: Service): MyRepository = MyRepositoryImpl(service)` ?

Comment: You either gonna use provider functions or constructor injection.

Comment: I have tried your code, with a dummy Service class constructor injection, and everything works fine. Check you Service class setup